# php - purpose of url encode?

Tags: php, urlencode

According to W3 schools :

> URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet.
>   URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>   Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

I have a url encode statement following an insert query :

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_1 VALUES ('0','".mysql_escape_string($forename)."','".mysql_escape_string($surname)."', '".mysql_escape_string($username)."', '".mysql_escape_string($password)."', '".mysql_escape_string($email)."')";

if(mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query)) {
$message = " - You have successfully registered";
header("Location: register.php?message=".urlencode($message));
} else {
die("Query was: $Query. Error: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Why is it necessary? Because characters such as @ in an e-mail address are being sent in the header redirect?

Comment: Isn't w3schools explanation enough? (it's not entirely correct though)

Comment: What do you mean it's not entirely correct?!

Comment: it mentions ASCII for some reason, while only a narrow subset of ASCII characters is allowed there. Check my answer for a further explanation.

Answer (score 3):

As per [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

```
URI           = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
```

And [RFC2234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234)

```
HEXDIG        = DIGIT / "A" / "B" / "C" / "D" / "E" / "F"
ALPHA         = %x41-5A / %x61-7A   ; A-Z / a-z
DIGIT         = %x30-39             ; 0-9
```

So it's required by a standard.

PS: as you can see `@` is a valid character to be used in a query as-is without additional encoding.